# Discord - Can anyone other than admin see the code inside bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, bots

I am planning on writing a Discord bot in JavaScript. I couldn't really find an answer to this, so hopefully I won't get too many wrong feedback.

Can my Discord bot code be seen by anyone? or by Discord itself? I am building a public/private key authentication and I need to include private key in the Discord bot's code so that it can digitally sign messages. Is this safe or what do I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding private keys to your code, **NEVER** put them in your code directly, always reference it as either an environment variable or a config file. No, people shouldn't be able to see your code, but that's really no excuse when you have an option where *even if* someone sees your code, your private keys are still protected.

Comment: true, but are you saying discord bot supports env variables that can be private and nobody can see ?

Comment: What are you talking about? You'll be the one hosting the bot, not discord. There's **nothing** that's accessible from outside your server.

Discord is only providing you an api to send messages using their service, nothing more.

Comment: ah, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's the same process when sending a message through telegram, or whatsapp, or any other service really. They give you some way do send then the text you want on the message, the person you want to receive it, and the token for your bot, to ensure it's really you sending that request.

As long as you don't send private information in the message itself, no one will even know about the existence of said private information, much less be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to do, so long as the source code is not shared on a site like github. In that case, I recommend using a .env file and including that in your .gitignore.

Comment: how can it be possible that discord bot code can't be even seen by discord itself ? who can assure me of this ? does docs somewhere mention this at least ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili How could discord see your code? That doesn't make any sense.